# ¿Se podrán llenar items de un combobox con un id del cliente de un textbox que aparezcan todas las mascotas que tiene el cliente enlazado a SQL en C#?

Tags: c#, sql

[image: Llenar combobox de mascotas poniendo dentro del textbox de cliente su id, y que con esa id, aparezca todas las mascotas que tienen el cliente]

Llenar combobox de mascotas poniendo dentro del textbox de cliente su id, y que con esa id, aparezca todas las mascotas que tienen el cliente

Comment: Voy a crear una nueva pregunta mejor detallada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta para obtener las mascotas por cliente seria algo como

```
public DataTable ObtenerMascotasPorCliente(int clienteId)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string connstring = "...";
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        string query = "SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM Mascotas WHERE ClienteId = @Id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", clienteId);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;

}
```

Para usarlo seria

```
int clienteId = 0;
if(int.TryParse(txtCliente.Text, out clienteId)){
   MessageBox.Show("el id del cliente no es valido");
   return;
}

ClassAccesoDatos obj = new ClassAccesoDatos();
var dt = obj.ObtenerMascotasPorCliente(clienteId);

comboMascotas.ValueMember = "campo1";
comboMascotas.DisplayMember = "campo2";
comboMascotas.DataSource = dt;
```

Entiendo que esa funcionalidad la pones en una clase por eso lo instancias

Comment: int clienteId = 0;
if(int.TryParse(txtCliente.Text, out clienteId)){
   MessageBox.Show("el id del cliente no es valido");
   return;
}

eso se agrega en el botón para buscar el id de cliente?

Comment: exacto, es solo una validacion del input del usuario para verificar que escribio un numero valido, es opcional si tienes otro tipo de validacion implementado

Answer (score 1):

--Si, es posible, yo te recomiendo que utilices un botón, luego de que se ingrese el id del cliente, que se ejecute lo siguiente

--En mi caso, yo cree una clase que contenia la conexion con la base de datos, y varios metodos, dejo aqui el metodo para llenar combobox

--Conexion con la base de datos

```
static OleDbConnection prpConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = TuBaseDeDatos.accdb"); //En mi caso era una base de datos de Access
```

static OleDbCommand prpSQL;

--El metodo para cargar el combobox

```
public static DataTable mthLoadData(string operation)
    {
        DataTable data = null;
        try
        {
            prpConnection.Open();
            prpSQL = new OleDbCommand(operation, prpConnection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = prpSQL.ExecuteReader();
            prpSQL.Dispose();
            if (reader != null)
            {
                data = new DataTable();
                data.Load(reader);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Datos no se pueden mostrar en este momento: " + e.Message + " Contacte a su administrador.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        prpConnection.Close();
        return data;
    }
```

--Lo siguiente es lo que deberias porgramar en el boton

```
string select = "SELECT * FROM tipoMembresia"; //La consulta en mi caso obtiene todos los datos de la tabla 'tipoMembresia'
        cmbTipo.DataSource = clsData.mthLoadData(select); //'clsData' es la clase creada, que escribí al inicio
        cmbTipo.ValueMember = "idTipoMembresia"; //'idTipoMembresia es mi llave principal y es la columna que contiene los id's (en tu caso el id de la mascota) y este valor NO se muestra en el combobox
        cmbTipo.DisplayMember = "tipoMembresia"; //'tipoMembresia es la columna que contiene los nombres de las membresias (en tu caso, los nombres de las mascotas) y este es el valor que Si se muestra en el combobox
        cmbTipo.SelectedIndex = -1; //Esta sentencia solo es para que el combobox aparezca sin nada seleccionado desde un principio
```

Comment: ¿En que parte se agrega lo que pongas en el textbox para que haga esa busqueda?